# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tuples

I am trying to convert a list into a tuple after finding the sum of all the previous elements but it is giving me 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'`

The code is

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(a)):
    sum=2
    for j in range(i):
        sum+=a[j]
    a[i]=(a[i],sum)
print(a)
```

Expected Output:
`[(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,8),(5,12)]`

And also can anyone please explain why when I do `sum+=a[i]` the code is working fine but is always producing an error when `sum+=a[j]`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar [(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,8),(5,12)]

Comment: You set elements in `a` to a tuple with `a[i]=(a[i],sum)`. You then try to add these elements to `sum`, which is an integer, with `sum+=a[j]`.

Comment: Do you see how in the first pass of the loop you're modifying `a[0]` to be a tuple, then in the next pass you're trying to add a tuple to an int?  Instead, you should be creating a new list of tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of first iteration, elements in `a` become a tuple and in the next iteration you do `sum += a[j]`. Here, `sum` is int and `a[j]` is tuple. Hence, your error.

You should ideally append tuples to a whole new list as below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

lst = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    sum = 2
    for j in range(i):
        sum += a[j]
    lst.append((a[i], sum))

print(lst)
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 8), (5, 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With one loop:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = []
sum_ = 2
for i in a:
    result.append((i, sum_))
    sum_ += i
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 8), (5, 12)]
```